# Are either AML or KYC process questions in scope for this site?

Tags: discussion

I work at a federally insured financial institution in the USA.

Would questions on AML and /or KYC be in scope for this site? There are anomalous events I am seeing where I work and want to check if such questions are in scope before I ask.

AML is anti money laundering and KYC is know your customer. These are legally mandated via federal US laws such as Bank Secrecy Act and Patriots Act

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the question. AML in particular and CFT are highly legislated and specialised fields which differ from country to country and industry. My gut feeling is to say no, it's off topic.

Mainly because taking the wrong advice can get companies bank accounts frozen and people in jail. And any questions should really be directed to your companies compliance officer as they should already be dealt with in the risk assessment and AML program documents.

Answer (score 1):

When I google AML it seems to be some type of nasty cancer. You may want to explain that, I have no idea if the actual thing you mean is on topic here.

Assuming that KYC is "know your customer" (again, please disambiguate, I don't feel like googling and making an educated guess every time I read a question), then that seems to be something that every workplace in a bank comes into contact with. Even if it has to do with laws and regulations, it's details is something that many bank employees should know, not only the lawyers. From a very high point of view, I would compare it to the GDPR. Yes, it's all laws and regulations, but everybody gets trained on it, there is specific persons in each company who receive even more training, and everybody has to be at least knowledgable enough to not break any laws in their day to day work. That is definetely on topic here.

Specific questions on how your company wants it done might still be "company dependent", because we cannot know, only the company does. And very theoretical questions might still be better to ask a lawyer because it goes way beyond regular employees knowledge. But generally speaking, there should be KYC question that are on topic here.

So to me it seems that practical questions around KYC that employees encounter during their regular work would be very much on topic here.

Comment: AML is anti money laundering. KYC is part of AML

Comment: Anythng to do with AML and KYC that employees deal with should be formally documented already and training given. There are no general answers, the formal documentation must be followed. Anything that's unusual or outside the training goes straight to designated personnel who then follow their documented processes or liaise with police/govt etc,.. Failure to do it properly has consequences up to and including business closure, fines, imprisonment and freezing of bank accounts and assets.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:

No.

Longer answer:

WP has a long standing policy of banning any question that is either a Company Policy question or a Legal question.

Company Policy questions are generally pretty easy: "My company says I can/can't do XYZ. I did W. Am I in trouble?"

Legal questions however we sometimes allow a little wiggle room.

As a general rule - if the question is tangentially about general legal principles, rather than a specific question on a specific element of law - we might allow it.

For example - Say someone described a scenario at work and wanted to know if it was wage theft. Most countries in the Anglosphere have broadly some form of Wage Theft law. A question like:

"I clocked in at 8:45, my shift starts at 9, but company policy says I have to be signed in 15 minutes before my shift - In my payslip, I see they have edited my clock-in time to 9 and only paid me for the changed hours. Is this wage theft?"

That's a common enough scenario, that is serves the mission of WPSE.

A more borderline question would be "I did XYZ, can I be fired?" Because if the OP is in the US and in an At-Will state, then the answer is always yes. If the OP is in New Zealand it could be no, but if they were in Australia it could be yes.

But again - we have some wiggle room, because it's such a common occurrence across multiple industries/countries etc.

Your question however:

1: Is highly specific to a single Industry.
2: Is highly specific to the US Federal Govt.
3: Is specifically about pieces of legislation and their application.

That's so niche as to be outside out goal of SE and it is the type of question that requires Legal knowledge of the minutiae and specifics of that legislation *and how they interact in practice*